# Remote host doesn't compile but it should

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans-6.9

I am using Netbeans and I am using a remote machine as Development host.

If this last is set to `localhost` everything builds fine, BUT when I move to the remote machine I have the error below ( it is really as it is outputted ).

The only difference is that my local is not 64 bit while the other one it is.

If I build the project on the remote machine using the same `makefile` I provided my Netbeans project I don't have any issue. 
Even when I try to provide the libraries with the file path hardcoded it doesn't work.

What's wrong and can you help me in fixing it?

Best Regards

AFG

```
      ../../../ix/libmylib.so.1.0: undefined reference to `xmlCleanupParser@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
      ../../../ix/libmylib.so.1.0: undefined reference to `xmlDictCleanup@LIBXML2_2.6.18'
      ../../../ix/libmylib.so.1.0: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
      ../../../ix/libfix.so.1.0: undefined reference to `__asprintf_chk@GLIBC_2.8'
      ../../../ix/libfix.so.1.0: undefined reference to `__vasprintf_chk@GLIBC_2.8
```

Comment: are you sure that all needed libraries installed on remote host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative paths to link, and the linking fails (not compilation). Either copy the libraries to correct path, or fix your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I found finally the reason why I got that error message. Under the project windows

```
 MyProject->Properties->General->Source Folders
```

I also included the directory containing the shared library I need to link.

Because of that also, the shared library was send to the remote server at build time. That it was a 32-bit shared library while I need one build remotely.

I added a project just for that shared library building each time before my project.